Is Goat milk chalavi?
Is goat milk treated the same as cows milk for the purpose of kashrut? Must it not be used along with meat, and must one wait after eating meat to have a dish cooked with goat milk?

Yes. Is there any reason you wouldn't think so? The original verse that we learn that all milk is forbidden with all meat is "do not cook a small goat in it's mother's milk"

Yes, absolutely. If you think about it, the Torah verse about all of this talks about cooking a g'di in its mother's milk. Now while the Talmud reads that as referring to any young animal, most often the term g'di means "a young sheep or goat."

That makes sense. Thank you!

B"H
Yes.
The original verse that we learn that all milk is forbidden with all meat is "do not cook a small goat in it's mother's milk"
Source

גדי לאו דוקא, דהוא הדין שור שה ועז. ולא שנא בחלב אֵם, לא שנא בחלב
אחרת, אלא שדבר הכתוב בהוה

